# How to bind an HTTP Angular 4/5 request to html?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object, angular-components

I have returned some raw JSON from an angular HTTPClient GET request and I am unsure how to now bind the properties of my JSON object to my html dynamically.

I would usually think to just store the returned JSON object into a variable and then reference it where I need it using dot notation, but Angular doesn't seem to work that way as I cannot set my http get request to a variable in ngOnInit and reference it.

I am using ngOnInit to initialize it when my Component loads and it is successfully logging to the console, but how do I get it binded INTO my html?

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Contacts';
  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get('**URL PATH RETURNING JSON OBJECT**')
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data));
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML:

```
<div id= contacts-container>
  <header><h1> {{ title }} </h1></header>
  <div id= "favoritesContainer">
    <p>Favorite Contacts</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
      <div *ngIf= "!contact.isFavorite">
          <img src={{contact.smallImageURL}} />
          <h3><img src="../assets/Favorite Star (True)/Favorite — True.png">{{ contact.name }} </h3>
          <br>
          <p>{{ contact.companyName }}</p>
          <hr>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Post sample data you are getting in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Contacts';
  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get('**URL PATH RETURNING JSON OBJECT**')
    .subscribe((data)=>{
         this.contacts = data;//I have assigned data here inside subscription
         console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

and reference `this.contacts` in same way you are doing in HTML

Comment: This works. This was a complete oversight and I feel silly. Thanks a lot! However, I am trying to save that to a variable in my `constructor()` using `contacts = any[];` and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting a compile error that I answered on another answer in this thread.

Comment: Guess u got the answer `contacts:any[]`

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have a `contacts` variable in your `app.component.ts`.

This is what it should look like:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Contacts';
  contacts: any[]; // Add variable
  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get('**URL PATH RETURNING JSON OBJECT**')
    .subscribe((data)=>{
         console.log(data);
         this.contacts = data; // Once you get the data, assign the data returned to contacts
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you should also init contacts to empty array just to be sure to avoid any undefined errors if there's a case of bigdata

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I am getting an error when I run this `./src/app/app.component.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`. When I run it without the `contacts = any[]` it works with the `this.contatcts` added to `ngOnInit`. Why would that not work?

Comment: Because I'm probably going to need to sort the JSON object eventually.

Comment: I think I found it. There is a slight typo in your answer. `contacts = any[];` should be `contacts: any[];`